# Using Flowplayer, autoplay false not working

Tags: javascript, video, flv, flowplayer, flash-video

On a Wordpress Site, I am trying to play a .flv file. I'm using the Flowplayer plugin that the client was using on their previous version of the site. The new site is in Wordpress, and one change request is that the video does not autoplay.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<a id="player" style="display: block; width: 475px; height: 370px;" href="[full path to file]/201110Janek.flv">
<object id="player_api" width="100%" height="100%" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="autoplay" value="false" />
<param name="cachebusting" value="false" />
<param name="flashvars" value="config={&quot;playerId&quot;:&quot;player&quot;,&quot;clip&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;[full path to file]/201110Janek.flv&quot;},&quot;playlist&quot;:[{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;[full path to file]/201110Janek.flv&quot;}]}" />
<param name="src" value="[full path to file]/flowplayer-3.2.15.swf" />
<embed id="player_api" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="[full path to file]/flowplayer-3.2.15.swf" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" quality="high" autoplay="false" cachebusting="false" flashvars="config={&quot;playerId&quot;:&quot;player&quot;,&quot;clip&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;[full path to file]/201110Janek.flv&quot;},&quot;playlist&quot;:[{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;[full path to file]/201110Janek.flv&quot;}]}" /></object></a>

<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[flowplayer("player", "[full path to file]/flowplayer-3.2.15.swf", {
clip: {
    // these two configuration variables does the trick
    autoPlay: false,
    autoBuffering: true}

    });
// ]]></script>
```

Everythings works fine, the video plays as it should, but it autoplays, despite the autoplay param and the autoPlay setting in the script.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?